# Why can't this conditional with generic keyof be eagerly resolved?

Tags: typescript

```
function broken<T>(value: T) {
  type Test = keyof T extends keyof T ? 1 : 0
}
```

Why can't `Test` in the example above be eagerly resolved to `1`? There's something I don't understand about the compiler that should answer this question for me.

Interestingly enough, there is a workaround:

```
function workaround<T>(value: T) {
  type Test = [keyof T] extends [keyof T] ? 1 : 0
}
```

Playground [here](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwE5wNYFMwB4AqAfABQBuAhgDYhYBci+AlIgN4BQiiUAngA5YMsAZyiIAvImzc4wBoiwAPKDgAmQyVmmz8iAPyIAjInoAGNgF82oSLASIA7nFQZy6cCoIkK1Og2btOHn5BEXFEAG0pGQYAXXklVXVIzWj8OP0jUwsgA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question probably involves [a bug fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29338) introduced in TypeScript 3.3.  The description of the new way of evaluating conditional types is:

> For a conditional type `T extends U ? X : Y`, the algorithm we use to determine whether to defer resolution of a conditional type is:
>
> - we resolve to `Y` when `T` is not assignable to `U` *considering all type parameters referenced in `T` and `U` related* (i.e. `T` is definitely not assignable to `U`),
> - otherwise we resolve to `X` when `T` is assignable to `U` *considering all type parameters referenced in `T` and `U` unrelated* (i.e. `T` is definitely assignable to `U`),
> - otherwise we defer resolution.

So it looks like `keyof T extends keyof T ? 1 : 0` is deferred, because `keyof T1` is not assignable to `keyof T2` when `T1` and `T2` are unrelated types.  This deferral isn't exactly *wrong*, but it does seem like a limitation.

Indeed if I [try your code in TS 3.2.1](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=3.2.1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwE5wNYFMwB4AqAfABQBuAhgDYhYBci+AlIgN4BQiiUAngA5YMsAZyiIAvImzc4wBoiwAPKDgAmQyVmmz8iAPyIAjInoAGNgF82VoA) it is eagerly resolved, so this was a change introduced for TS3.3.

Curiously my reading of that bug fix's algorithm description looks like it should apply to your workaround also.  I'm not sure why `[keyof T] extends [keyof T]` would change things, since `[keyof T1]` isn't definitely assignable to `[keyof T2]`, if `T1` and `T2` are unrelated.  So some mystery still remains here.  Haven't been able to crack it yet, so I'll probably just give up now.  Oh well!

---

It also looks like someone [reported this exact issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29505) where `X extends X ? 1 : 0` is not eagerly resolved (and they also noticed that wrapping in a one-tuple "fixes" it), and the issue was tagged as a bug, so maybe it will be addressed?

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!